# How to install Java3D on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-3d, mason-abm

I'm using an agent-based modelling toolkit called [MASON](https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/) in Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and I need Java3D to get some of the tutorials to work.

**Can anyone guide me through installing Java (JDK, JRE, 3D etc.) on a Mac and getting Eclipse setup correctly?**

I have tried to follow the instructions [here](https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/), [here](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/mart/entry/installing_java3d_1_5_on), but still no luck. I've downloaded [Apple's Java for OSX](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and can get the non-3D tutorials to work, so I'm halfway there. I think.

Myself and some others in my department have tried all day but to no avail. Everyone has a slightly different setup and no one can currently get it to work on my MacBook.

Comment: Sorry but my instructions contain a lot of details and work under OS X Yosemite 10.10. However, you must NOT mix the files in https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/j3dlibs.zip with those I mention in my tutorial and you must NOT rely on the extension mechanism. Oracle abandoned Java3D 1.5 in 2008, rather use Java3D 1.6 with Oracle Java or OpenJDK. Apple Java is no longer maintained.